# Azure - a simple reverse proxy with static IP

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy

I am struggling to have a simple service acting as a reverse proxy in Azure.
I need it because the API that I want to communicate with uses IP whitelisting. That's why I want to set up a reverse proxy service with a static IP. My application (whose IP is cannot be static) would communicate with the target API via the reverse proxy.

With some research I found the following options:

1. Creating a Web App with some custom IIS config - I'm not sure if that's still valid, because the guides I found are pretty old
2. API Management - that seems pretty heavy and I've heard it's not going to be easy to configure
3. Application Gateway - that requires a VNet, which I do not even need.
4. Azure Function with Proxy - I think that option is no longer available with Functions V4. What's more, I would have to also set up NAT Gateway to have a single outbound IP. That seems overly complicated.
5. Creating a custom Web App with code that does the proxy logic

All these options seem to be too complicated for a simple task that I need. Basically, I want to have public reverse proxy, when I hit https://my-reverse-proxy.com/*, the proxy would return data from https://my-whitelisted-api.com/*.

Is there any easier alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Azure services where you host your app has a single outbound ip or a range of outbound ip-addresses that can be whitelisted, but it's hard to know if that works in your case as you did not mention in what Azure service you host your app.

A generic solution could be that you provision an Nginx proxy in Azure Container Apps. Then you will will have the Container Apps Environment public ip address as outbound ip to whitelist. Beware though that anyone can call your proxy from any ip, which means that you are completely disabling the protection they put in place by whitelisting ips and opening up their API to the whole world. So without knowing your circumstances, this would probably not be recommended.

Comment: Well, my app is a JS webapp, so it can execute on any client IP. Yes, I know, the API will be open to the world via the proxy, but it's not a problem, because it's also protected with oauth2 access tokens. Hmm, I thought Azure offers something quick and easy to setup. I'll probably have to learn how to configure nginx. Thanks for the tip anyway. I also will have to check if Container Apps offer HTTPS endpoints. I used Container Instances in the past, they did not have HTTPS endpoints.

Comment: Ah, ok then I see. Azure App Gateway can also do this and much easier. Have a look here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works). The image shows a backend that is an external API (on-premises/external app servers).